# How does ContentCachingResponseWrapper work?

Tags: spring-mvc, servlet-filters

I understand that with `ContentCachingResponseWrapper`, the body of the response is cached and that can be read multiple times. But the function `getContentAsByteArray()` returns empty unless the `chain.doFilter()` method is called. I don't have another filter in my code, so I don't understand why this is the case.

For example my code is:

```java
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    System.out.println("In ServletFilter");
    HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;
    ContentCachingResponseWrapper ccrw = new ContentCachingResponseWrapper(res);
    
    chain.doFilter(request, ccrw); // If this statement is not executed then content is empty

    String content = new String(ccrw.getContentAsByteArray(), "UTF-8");
    System.out.println(content);   // This prints empty if the chain.doFilter() is not executed
}
```

Comment: What is it you don't understand? The read content is only filled when it is actually being read, else it is empty. `getContentAsByteArray` only returns the content that has been read, so if nothing has been read (yet) it returns `null`.

Comment: So @M.Deinum my question would be how does calling the ```chain.doFilter()``` method read the content?

Comment: It doesn't, it makes it pass further on the filter chain and eventually the servlet handling the request. If you omit that call, the request won't be handled.

Comment: @M.Deinum But why does the positioning of the ```chain.doFilter()``` method matter? If I call the ```getContentAsByteArray()``` before calling ```chain.doFilter()``` then the print statement is empty otherwise it prints the actual response body.

Comment: Why wouldn't it. You are calling a method before something has had the change of consuming the body and expect it to have pre-filled the cache? So you expect that when calling `getContentAsByteArray`, before the request is handled, it should magically know that you are still going to call `doFilter()` and that there is something downstream that is consuming the body...